# Getting error "Request to a downlevel service failed" when deploying to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

As of today I have begun getting the following error when I try to deploy our *ASP.NET* web services to our **Azure web hosting** from **Team Foundation Services** 2015.

[image]

Getting down to the details of the error message we have the following.

[image]

It generates warnings when executing the **Get-AzureWebsite** script then generates an error when executing the **New-AzureWebsite** script.

This has been working for several years without a problem but as of today it is now generating an error. I am unable to deploy our latest code changes because of this error.

**UPDATE**

After some investigation it appears as if the **Azure** scripts that are used to underpin the **TFS** tasks have all been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/servicebus/deprecating-service-management-support-for-azure-service-bus-relay-and-event-hubs). Which therefore begs the question, what is the migration path for those deploying to **Azure** using **TFS** 2015? Is there a new **TFS** task which will use the new scripts instead? How do I update my **TFS** deployment so that it doesn't generate this error?

**UPDATE2**

I have installed the latest **PowerShell** and installed the *Azure RM Automation* cmdlets. I have updated the script *Publish-AzureWebDeployment.ps1* to use **Get-AzureRmWebApp** instead of **Get-AzureWebSite** and **New-AzureRmWebApp** instead of **New-AzureWebSite** but I'm still getting errors.

Have Microsoft provided any updates to TFS or the underlying Azure deployment scripts since deprecating the old Azure scripts? Surely Microsoft aren't expecting the developers to re-write these scripts ourselves?

[image]

Comment: In Octopus we are getting the same error message when we try to deploy a package to Azure App Service -> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudException: <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Request to a downlevel service failed.</string>

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to the my problem was a workaround. Instead of deploying my application to our **Azure** hosting using an **Azure Web App Deployment** task, I have created an *FTP* script that does this. I am using *WinSCP* as this can be run from the command line and has the ability to easily synchronise your local and remote directories without to write any complex FTP commands. It does this

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /script=ftpDeployServices.ftp
```

And here's the FTP script *ftpDeployServices.ftp*.

```
option batch abort
option confirm off 
option transfer binary
open ftp://myusername:mydomain.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot
cd /site/wwwroot
synchronize remote -delete "C:\DEV" /site/wwwroot
close 
exit
```